# Regression model in Python for engineering equipment end of life prediction - improvements and suggestions

Tags: machine-learning, regression, ridge-regression

I am trying to build a ML prediction model that uses the calculated remaining part life, machine power consumption, and other related process parameters specific to the equipment in question, to determine a model that will be able to predict part life based on power consumption.

I have followed the following steps to build the current model:

import data
Check for null values in the data and drop these rows
Visualized the data and seen that its a linear trend between part life (Y) and power consumption (X) (figure 1) [image: Figure 1]
Used StandardScaler to normalize the data
Split my data into X and Y dataframes
I checked the correlation on X data and there is a very strong correlation (all are greater that 0.85). For this reason, I have used Ridge Regression
Split my data into train and test splits
Fit the data to the ridge regression model using a value of alpha to be 1
From these steps, this is the output I am getting (Figure 2)[image: Figure 2]

I have just started with machine learning and I am the only one in my company working on this. Please could you advise if I have followed the correct steps, used the correct logic and where I could improve my modelling for this example?

Comment: This looks like a perfect start! I would recommend you to analyze the model by analyzing the accuracy metrics like RMSE, MSE. You should work to improve the metrics and can also use grid search CV to rule out overfitting and underfitting. You can also continue to use advanced regression modelling techniques like random forest, gradient descent, neural networks, etc. You can then compare the validation metrics and decide which model will best suit your data.